# Unlink visuals in duplicated page

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

With PBI Desktop (may 2022 version), when you duplicate a page, visualizations on both pages are automatically linked. It means that any changes made on one of the pages will be reflected on the other duplicated page. How can I disassociate one from another?

Comment: What changes are you making? I've tried filters & changing visual type but they're not reflected on the other page. Granted I'm on a more recent version of Desktop (April 2023) so the behaviour may have changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View -> Sync slicers -> Sync slicers pane.

Unchecking left checkbox will unlink visuals and unchecking right checkbox will remove it from that page

[image: sync pane]